# Is there an array creation function for full arrays that has the same signature as sparse matrix constructor?

Tags: matlab

I'd like to accumulate indexed elements in a matrix, like table and tapply function in R.

I found sparse(i,j,s,m,n) fit my need perfectly,

As the document says:"Any elements of s that have duplicate values of i and j are added together."

But I have to convert the obtained sparse matrix to a full one using full():

```
a =　a + full(sparse(i,j,s,m,n));
```

Is this a efficient way to do so?

---

By the way, is there anything like below, no matter whether adding duplicated i,j pairs?

```
a = setelements(a, i,j,s);
```

and

```
vector = getelement(a,i,j);
```

where i&j take meanings in sparse() function.

---

And what if a is a multidimensional array? sparse() only deal with matrix.
Do I have to set the entries page by page with outer loops?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [`accumaray`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html). For example,

```
ii = [1 2 2 3 3];
jj = [3 2 2 2 2];
s = [10 20 30 40 50];
a = accumarray([ii(:) jj(:)],s(:));
```

gives

```
a =

     0     0    10
     0    50     0
     0    90     0
```

Note that each row of the first argument (`[ii(:) jj(:)]`) defines an N-dimensional index into the output array (N is 2 in this example).

`accumarray` is very flexible. It works for N-dimensional arrays, lets you specify size of the result (it may be larger than inferred from the supplied indices), and can even apply an arbitrary function (different from sum) to each set of values defined by the same index.

As a more general example, with the above data,

```
a = accumarray([ii(:) jj(:)],s(:),[4 4],@max)
```

gives

```
a =

     0     0    10     0
     0    30     0     0
     0    50     0     0
     0     0     0     0
```

Comment: Perfectly match! You're so brilliant!